# ASP.NET DynamicData - add table at runtime?

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, asp.net-dynamic-data

We currently have an ASP.NET Dynamic Data website for our intranet that was developed by a contractor who is no longer with us.

None of our developers currently have VS 2008 installed, so are not able to open modify the source code of this intranet site to add 2 new tables to the site.  The new tables require simple CRUD operations exactly like the existing 6 tables in the site.

Is it possible to modify the .dbml file inside the App_Data directory on our ASP server in order to provide these new tables using the DD scaffolding, or will I need to source and install VS 2008 in order to be able to add 2 simple templated tables?

Comment: Limited research tells me that .dbml files are related to Linq to Sql. Thus the retag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Visual Studio 2008.  Open the project and be done with it.  VS 2008 and VS 2005 and VS 2003 coexist very well side by side.

Comment: <sarcasm>
Thanks for the useful answer
</sarcasm>
Procuring and upgrading to a new version of VS 2008, while not impossible, is not going to be a trivial task in our enterprise environment.  It is this sort of "cavalier" attitude got us into this trouble in the first place.  If said contractor hadn't been so blinded by the "new-shinyness" he would have used plain, vanilla ASP.NET.  Now he has left the building, I am left to clean up the mess. Now I have to get this fixed without blowing budget, and within the next couple of days :(

Comment: I take that back.  Sorry.  Visual Studio 2008 is a dangerous program which could destroy your company if you install it.  I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: I believe you forgot your own <sarcasm/> tags? ;)  Okay, okay, looks like I'm out of alternatives, and am going to have to bite the bullet and install VS2008.  I agree, the act of installing VS08 is not going to make the stock prices here collapse and/or contaminate the oceans, it's just going to take a while to purchase the software through the appropriate channels. Thanks, Brett

Comment: Another option is to use the tools that come with .NET itself (you should be able to use MSBuild from the command line and compile manually).  While this may cost nothing, you may have a long learning curve to ride.  If money's really tight, look up SharpDevelop.

Answer (score 0):

I thought Developer Express 2008 provides Dynamic Data capabilities.  Perhaps someone can download a (free) copy, develop the app on an "isolated" box, and go from there.